# $\int^\infty_1 (\frac{e}{x})^x$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis

How would I show $\int^\infty_1 (\frac{e}{x})^x$ exists? I don't have a clue on even how to start. Will inequality be used here? Any hints will be helpful. Please do not post solutions, thanks!

Comment: If $x\ge e^2$ then $\left(\frac ex\right)^x\le e^{-x}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\left(\frac ex\right)^x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_1^3\left(\frac ex\right)^x\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_3^\infty\left(\frac ex\right)^x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\int_1^3\left(\frac ex\right)^x\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_3^\infty\left(\frac e3\right)^x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: ..I actually thought about this at first, but how do you deal with something have a variable in its exponent. ?

Comment: @Kun: do you know the formula for $\int e^{ax}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: No. We haven't studied taylor series yet, So I guess I cannot use it..

Comment: Can I deal with it with some sequences? Our teacher suggested $\sum (\frac{e}{n})^n,$ but I cannot figure anything out..

Comment: @Kun: if you know that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{ax}=a\,e^{ax}$, then you can get $\int e^{ax}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1a\,e^{ax}+C$

Comment: Oh it is decreasing function, it sits underneath the sum, So I might be able to do that..

Comment: @Kun: $a^x = e^{x \ln a}$. So $\int a^x dx = \frac{1}{\ln a}x^a+C$. Now put $a=\frac{e}{3}$.

Comment: Ok, then what happen to the $x^x$

Comment: Sorry, I see what you saying

Comment: @Kun: we used $\frac ex\le\frac e3$ to get rid of the $x$ in the denominator for $x\ge3$.

Answer (score 7):

We have

$$\left(\frac ex\right)^x=\exp\left(-x\ln\frac{x}{e}\right)\le e^{-x}\quad\text{for sufficently large}\; x$$
and the result follows.

Comment: for $x\ge e^2$, to be exact.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint :** $$\begin{align}\int_1^\infty\bigg(\frac ex\bigg)^x~dx&~=~\int_1^3\bigg(\frac ex\bigg)^x~dx+\int_3^\infty\bigg(\frac ex\bigg)^x~dx~\le~\\&~\le~\int_1^3\bigg(\frac e1\bigg)^x~dx+\int_3^\infty\bigg(\frac e3\bigg)^x~dx.\end{align}$$ Can you take it from here ?